# Python Regular Expression: Matching Car Speeds without Highway Names

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I'm trying to match speed descriptions of highway tickets, for example,text lines:

"L A 16-25MPH" should return 2 groups:    16, 25 
"LMT ACC 6-10" should return 2 groups: 6, 10 
"6 OVER" should return 1 group: 6
I'm OK with all of the above situations, but I run into issues for strings with numbers that aren't related to speed, for example:

"LIMITED ACCESS SPEED I-75" should return no matches.
 The closest expression I can get to capture all needed is: `((?<!\w-)\d+)[^\d]*((?<!\w-)\d+)?`, which would match 1 group: 5, using the python regular expression engine

For now, it's safe to assume that a letter then a hyphen (`\w-`) is what I'm trying to use a negative lookback to exclude, I'm just not sure how to group more than one digit(`\d+`) to use the negative lookback.

Comment: Try like this: [`(?<!\S)(\d+)(?:-(\d+))?`](https://regex101.com/r/yG7aY6/1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Description

```regex
([0-9]+)(?:-([0-9]+)|\s*over)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

<sub>** To see the image better, simply right click the image and select view in new window</sub>

This regular expression will do the following:

- Matches numbers related to speeds
- avoid numbers that are part of road names

## Example

**Live Demo**

https://regex101.com/r/hE5dL4/2

**Sample text**

Note: the edge case about `I-75`

```
'm trying to match speed descriptions of highway tickets, for example,text lines:

"L A 16-25MPH" should return 2 groups: 16, 25 
"LIMITED ACCESS SPEED I-75" should return no matches.
"LMT ACC 6-10" should return 2 groups: 6, 10 
"6 OVER" should return 1 group: 6

I'm OK with all of the above situations, but I run into issues for strings with numbers that aren't related to speed, for example:

"LIMITED ACCESS SPEED I-75" should return no matches.
```

**Sample Matches**

```
MATCH 1
1.  [89-90] `16`
2.  [91-93] `25`

MATCH 2
1.  [193-194]   `6`
2.  [195-197]   `10`

MATCH 3
1.  [231-232]   `6`
```

## Explanation

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [0-9]+                   any character of: '0' to '9' (1 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    -                        '-'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (                        group and capture to \2:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      [0-9]+                   any character of: '0' to '9' (1 or
                               more times (matching the most amount
                               possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of \2
----------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0
                             or more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    over                     'over'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: I think this is very very close, but the first 16 in your live demo only has the 6 captured.

I tried modifying it a little bit:

    (\d+)(?:-(\d+)|\s*over)

This seems to work. Let me know if you see any major flows. Also, thank you for your help :)

Comment: The six is from the string `"6 OVER" should return 1 group: 6` where there are no additional numbers to match.

Comment: I may be mistaken, but for match1 it matches 6 & 25 but should be 16 & 25. Perhaps I'm missing something, as I'm quite new to regex- but I can't see any other way to read it.

Comment: Oh I see what you're talking about, yes I had the written `([0-9])+` which was wrong. It should have been `([0-9]+)`. On a side note I see you're using the `\d` character class. I recommend against using that because it's not as efficient as `[0-9]`

Comment: Great, that works! Thanks for the advice as well regarding the \d character class!

Answer (score 3):

*Negative lookbehinds* must be of fixed length (see the [Python doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) for more detail), so things like `\d+` would not be allowed.

You could use a lookbehind to check for certain fixed-width indicators of highways, though, such as `I` and `RT` (case-insensitive). You may also want to add additional cases to add a space around the dash, no dash at all, etc.

One option that may fit the criteria (set the insensitive flag): `(?<!i|rt)(\d+)`